# Find XML element with specific value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have some XML with the following structure:

```
<pressureVessel>
  <closure1>
    <topClosure>
      <ellipsoidalHead>
        <standardComponentData>
          <identifier>Ellipsoidal Head #1</identifier>
          <idNumber>1111</idNumber>
          ...
        </standardComponentData>
      </ellipsoidalHead>
    </topClosure>
  </closure1>
  <closure2>
    <bottomClosure>
      <ellipsoidalHead>
        <standardComponentData>
          <identifier>Ellipsoidal Head #2</identifier>
          <idNumber>2222</idNumber>
          ...
        </standardComponentData>
      </ellipsoidalHead>
    </topClosure>
  </closure1>
  <shell>
    <cylinder>
      <standardComponentData>
        <identifier>Cylinder #1</identifier>
        <idNumber>3333</idNumber>
        ...
      </standardComponentData>
      ....
     </cylinder>
    <cylinder>
      <standardComponentData>
        <identifier>Cylinder #2</identifier>
        <idNumber>4444</idNumber>
        ...
      </standardComponentData>
      ....
     </cylinder>
    <cylinder>
      <standardComponentData>
        <identifier>Cylinder #3</identifier>
        <idNumber>5555</idNumber>
        ...
      </standardComponentData>
      ....
    </cylinder>
    <flange>
      <standardComponentData>
        <identifier>Top Head Flange #1</identifier>
        <idNumber>6666</idNumber>
        <attachedToidNumber>1111</attachedToidNumber>
        ...
      </standardComponentData>
    </flange>
  </shell>
<pressureVessel>
```

I'm in some javascript that is parsing this XML, and I have the flange element as a variable called `bomNode`. What I need to do is find the element whose `<idNumber>` value  matches the `>attachedToidNumber>` in the `<flange>` element (in this case, Ellipsoidal Head #1). There are multiple other elements within `<pressureVessel>`, so what I need to do is

1. Find any element that starts with `closure` (e.g. closure1, closure2, etc).
2. Within that element, find a child element that has `<standardComponentData>` and then an `<idNumber>` value that matches the `<attachedToidNumber>` (which I have stored in a variable at that point).
3. Get that element so I can get other data from it.

So what is the most efficient way to do this? There are other elements under `<pressureVessel>`, so I don't want to parse all of them if I don't have to.

My thoughts are to do something like

```
var elName = 'closure';
bomNode.parent().parent().find().has(elName).each(function(index() {
  // Do something here
})
```

but I'm not sure where to go from here, or if I'm even on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()` to get match the `<idNumber>` element where `.textContent` is equal to `<attachedToIdNumber>` `.textContent`

```
$(xml).find("standardComponentData idNumber").filter(function(i, el) {
  return $(el).parents().filter(function(i, el) { 
           return /closure/i.test(el.tagName)  }).is("*") 
         && el.textContent === xml.find("attachedToidNumber").text()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a shot at it based on my best understanding of your use case and a slightly more complete (but still guessing at it) XML file.

1. I made an array of all the available nodes that began with `closure`.
2. From there, populated another array (called `attachableComponents`) with any elements that contained a `<standardComponentData>` node.
3. Then, it was a matter of creating a function that finds any of those elements.
4. Passing the value of a `<flang>`'s `<attachedToidNumber>` to that function pulls out any matching nodes from inside that `attachableComponents` array.

Example JS Bin that renders it out for visual reference:

http://jsbin.com/hovovel/1/edit?html,js,output